# How to manage sub-pages under main MVC website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, database-design

I'm currently developing an ASP.NET MVC website that consists of a main page with many sub pages, with their own content and features (i.e. item ordering, service request forms, contact pages, etc.). It will look similar to this example structure:

- Main Page

  - Sub Page "Clubs"

    - Arts
      -- Submit Painting
      -- List of Members
      -- Activities
    - Kitchen
      -- Recipes
      -- Join Newsletter
  - Sub Page "Resources"

    - Attendance System
    - Club Management Program

How can I manage the Views and Controllers so this can be possible? Should I create one controller for each sub page, or is there a way to keep all the controller actions in the same controller? Should I make an automatic approach with some type of database? I'm looking for a simple solution that allows for easy upgrading if required.

Here is an example image of what I mean, including the parent navbar:
[image: Example Webpage Mockup]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have so many ideas in mind, why not convert those ideas to code, you might not know the best route to follow, until you actually start coding. So first advice, try out one of your ideas and share what you've done here. Secondly, you could try **MVC Partial views**.

Comment: Thank you. I currently have the main webpage running in MVC and the other pages are in development. However, I would like to know if it was better to develop each sub-website separately (controller and views for each) or create a master controller that generates the views for each for example "club" upon request, maybe with a pre-determined template for all.